# Linux "cross-compilation" for different GLIBC version

Tags: c++, c, linux, glibc

My work configuration is that I have Ubuntu-20-based development workstation (exactly Linux Mint 20.1) where I develop application for Ubuntu 18. When I compile simple C or C++ program, upload it to the target machine and run, I receive the message:

```
./test: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by ./test)
./test: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by ./test)
```

Can I force the program to link to the older version? I use gcc 9 if it does matter.

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to set up a build environment for the older version of Ubuntu in a Docker container or a virtual machine. Containers are preferable because they are less wasteful of system memory.

Answer (score 2):

The canonical solution is create a chroot environment for the target version with debootstrap, as:

`debootstrap --variant=buildd --arch amd64 bionic ~/bionic_chroot`

and activating that chroot with

`chroot ~/bionic_chroot`

and do the compilation within chroot. See for example [here](https://wiki.debian.org/chroot) for further details.

Comment: Do I have to install also another copy of compiler, cmake, and other development tools?

Comment: Some of the packages needed for development (like gcc, make,...) are installed due the usage of `--variant=buildd' option, but the development dependencies of your project need to be installed, just as you did on your original system. And you need to get your a copy of your sources into the chroot, either copying it before your activate the chroot, or install git within the chroot environment, and clone the source tree.